# Fastest way to check if an URL is valid in bash script

Tags: bash, file

I have a file called `test`. It looks like this (sample):

```
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/!!!> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/MusicalArtist> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/!!!_(álbum)> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Album> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/!Kung_Ekoka> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Language> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/!_(álbum)> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Album> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/!_(álbum_de_Trippie_Redd)> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Album> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/$9.99> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/$h*!_My_Dad_Says> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/TelevisionShow> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/%22A%22_de_adulterio> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Book> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/%22B%22_de_bestias> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Book> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/%22C%22_de_cadáver> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Book> .
```

I have made an script that returns in two different files `invalid_instance_types` and `valid_instance_types` the triplets with valid and invalid URLs respectively of `test` file (only the first URL between `<` and `>` is checked for each line).

When an URL is invalid, if you click it, it displays the following message: `No further information is available. (The requested entity is unknown)`. Example: http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/does_not_exist

This the script I've made:

```
echo "Separating valid and invalid URLs"
while read line;
do
    url=`echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f1 | cut -d'<' -f2 | cut -d'>' -f1`
    if ! wget -q --method=HEAD $url; then
        echo $line >> invalid_instance_types
    else
        echo $line >> valid_instance_types
    fi
done < test
echo "Done"
```

The problem is that it takes about 1 minute to check `test` file that has a total of 215 lines.

I have been investigating and what it takes more time to execute is the URL checking line:

```
! wget -q --method=HEAD $url
```

So, I want to find a way to do this but in less time.

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use regex

Comment: A HEAD request already is the “fast” way to determine the status code of a resource (as compared to a regular GET.) Your numbers mean, it takes roughly about 0.3 seconds for each of those requests, that is not too bad. Whether anything _can_ be speed up about this, probably depends mostly on the response time of the other system. (Assuming that the connection between the two is not the bottle neck here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a touch of caution, it might be worth trying to parallelise these to reduce the overall time. But you might hit some other bottleneck.

This is not tested, but hopefully might be enough to help you to give it a go:

```
## The fucntions does the checking. This will be called 
## as a async background process

function checkurl
{
    myline = $1
    myurl = $2
    if ! wget -q --method=HEAD $myurl; then
        echo $myline >> invalid_instance_types
    else
        echo $myline >> valid_instance_types
    fi
}

echo "Separating valid and invalid URLs"

$maxno=10
$cno = 0

while read line;
do
    url=`echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f1 | cut -d'<' -f2 | cut -d'>' -f1`
    checkurl  "$line" "$url" &

    ## Optional - have  a limit for number of submissions
    ## Not foolproof but can be tuned to taste and developed
    ## to be more accurate and robust, e.g check number of jobs
    ## running and limiting that to maxno.

    ((cno=cno+1))
    if [ $cno -gt $maxno ]
    then
       sleep 5
       cno=0
    fi

done < test

## Wait for all submitted processes to complete - using the 'while'
## loop might play tricks with this.
## If so, you could implement a sleep loop to periodically count
## the lines until
##   (wc -l test == (wc -l invalid_instance_types valid_instance_types))

echo "Waiting for all to complete"
wait
echo "Done"
```